# Access playbackState of MPMoviePlayerController within UI Test

Tags: xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to assess if a MPMoviePlayerViewController is playing or paused using XCTest's UI Testing framework?

I can manage to access the video element with this beautiful piece of code that was spit out by the recorder

```
[[[[[[[[app.otherElements[@"VideoPlayer_ViewController"] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther] elementBoundByIndex:0]
                                                         childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element
                                                         childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element
                                                         childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther] matchingIdentifier:@"Video"]
```

But I don't see anything in the XCUIElement interface or in the XCUIElementAttributes protocol that could help me assert that the player is playing or paused. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you able to access the player's source code?

Comment: Yes. Right now the only solution I can think oh would be to set the accessibilityValue of the player to @"playing" or @"paused" when it's playing or paused. Is that where you were going?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going to suggest. While in the source code, they might be the same button with a different image, to a user, they are different buttons with different functions, so it makes sense that they would be identified differently, since UI tests are simulations of user interaction.

Comment: In my case there aren't any button. But the user can tap on the video and that will present open a browser on top of the video. While the browser is shown the video should be paused. That what I want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting the `accessibilityValue` of the view of the view controller presenting the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` like so

```
- (void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        self.view.accessibilityValue = @"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying";
    }

    if (self.player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
        self.view.accessibilityValue = @"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused";
    }
}
```

Then I can access the value like this

```
// Playing
[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].otherElements[@"VideoPlayer_ViewController"].value isEqualToString:@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying"];
// Paused
[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].otherElements[@"VideoPlayer_ViewController"].value isEqualToString:@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused"];
```

Comment: I'd recommend setting the accessibility identifier instead of the value. Values are user facing, meaning Voice Over will read them.

Then in your test you can just check that the element exists instead of checking the value for that view controller.

Comment: Good point. I need to to read more about the meaning of the different accessibility properties.